# what is the proper way to keep track objects on a QTreeView/QStandardItem

Tags: c++, qt, object, qtreeview, qstandarditem

I have a `QTreeView` that has three branches under a rootnode

```
QTreeView treeView_4 = new QTreeView(tab_10);
QStandardItemModel standardModel = new QStandardItemModel ;
QStandardItem *rootNode = standardModel->invisibleRootItem();

QStandardItem Group1Item =  new QStandardItem("Group 1");
QStandardItem Group2Item =  new QStandardItem("Group 2");
QStandardItem Group3Item =  new QStandardItem("Group 3");

rootNode->appendRow(Group1Item);
rootNode->appendRow(Group2Item);
rootNode->appendRow(Group3Item);
```

I want to list some objects under Group1/2/3 when they are created. When a property of an Object changes, I want to move them from one group to another (like some status change). An object have two properties that is interesting for QTreeView:`QString IPaddress` and `QString Name`. **(I want to show either of them on the QtreeView)**

**What is the best/proper way to do it?**

```
class Object : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
//.... some properties, get and set functions, etc.
    QStandardItem *NodeItemIP;
    QStandardItem *NodeItemName;
private:
   QString Name;
   QString IPaddr;
///....
}
```

---

I store objects in a `QVector`: `QVector<Object*> mObject`

What I did to use `QMap` for each group to keep track

```
QMap<QString, QString> group1MapList;
QMap<QString, QString> group2MapList;
QMap<QString, QString> group3MapList;
```

and `insert` them to `Qmap` when they are appended to the `QStandardItem`

```
group1MapList.insert(mObject[1]->getName(), mObject[1]->getIPaddr());
Group1Item.appendRow(mObject[1]->NodeItemIP);
```

or

```
int index = 0;
QMap<QString, QString>::Iterator it;
for (it=group1MapList.begin(); it != group1MapList.end(); it++){
      if(it.value() == IPAddrToRemove){
      group1MapList.remove(IPAddrToRemove);
      Group1Item->removeRow(index);
      break;
   }
  index++;
}
```

I noticed that `QMap` (and `QHash` as well) does not store the entities in the order that they are added.

Is there any special class to keep track QStandardItems as I need or should I use **QVector** or anything else?

as I have two properties: `IPaddr` and `Name`, do I need to have two `QVector`s to track them or something can handle both of them?

Note: if there is no copy+paste/edit error, then above code snippets' syntax should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with `QTreeView`, maybe you must to create custom data structure to model the data tree. Something like this:

```
struct ModelItem
{
  QString groupName;
  QString name;
  QString IPaddr;
  ModelItem* parent;
  std::vector< ModelItem* > childs;

  ModelItem( const QString& a_name )
    : name( a_name ),
      parent( nullptr )
  { }

  ~ModelItem( )
  {
    for ( auto it = childs.begin( ); it != childs.end( ); ++it )
      delete *it;
  }

  void AddChild( ModelItem* children )
  {
    childs.push_back( children );
    children->parent = this;
  }
};
```

Of course, you need to subclass `QAbstractItemModel`:

```
class CustomModel : public QAbstractItemModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

  public:

    CustomModel( QObject* parent = nullptr );

    ~CustomModel( );

    int columnCount( const QModelIndex& parent ) const override;

    int rowCount( const QModelIndex& parent ) const override;

    QVariant data( const QModelIndex& index,
                   int role = Qt::DisplayRole ) const override;

    QModelIndex index ( int row,
                        int column,
                        const QModelIndex& parent ) const override;

    QModelIndex parent( const QModelIndex & index ) const override;

    void SetGroup( const QString& groupName,
                   const std::vector< std::pair< QString, QString > >& items );

    void ResetModel( );

  private:

    ModelItem rootNode;

};
```

columnCount and rowCount methods shall return the number of columns / rows of the model:

```
int CustomModel::columnCount( const QModelIndex& /* parent */ ) const
{
  return 1;
}

int CustomModel::rowCount( const QModelIndex& parent ) const
{

  int to_return;

  if ( parent.isValid( ) )
  {
    ModelItem* node = static_cast< ModelItem* >( parent.internalPointer( ) );
    to_return = node->childs.size( );
  }
  else
    to_return = rootNode.childs.size( );

  return to_return;
}
```

data method shall return the content of the model:

```
QVariant CustomModel::data( const QModelIndex& index,
                            int role ) const
{
  QVariant to_return;

  if ( index.isValid( ) ) // if not valid, current index is root node
  {
    switch ( role )
    {
      case Qt::DisplayRole: // you can manage other roles to enrich the view
      {
        ModelItem* node = static_cast< ModelItem* >( index.internalPointer( ) );
        to_return = node->name;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return to_return;
}
```

index will create appropiate `QModelIndex` of given node:

```
QModelIndex CustomModel::index ( int row,
                                 int column,
                                 const QModelIndex& parent ) const
{
  QModelIndex to_return;

  if ( ( row >= 0 && row < rowCount( parent ) )
    && ( column >= 0 && column <= columnCount( parent ) ) )
  {
    if ( parent.isValid( ) )
    {
      ModelItem* item = static_cast< ModelItem* >( parent.internalPointer( ) );
      to_return = createIndex( row, column, item->childs.at( row ) );
    }
    else
    {
      to_return = createIndex( row, column, rootNode.childs.at( row ) );
    }
  }

  return to_return;
}
```

parent method shall return de index of the parent of given node

```
QModelIndex CustomModel::parent( const QModelIndex & index ) const
{
  QModelIndex to_return;

  if ( index.isValid( ) )
  {
    ModelItem* node = static_cast< ModelItem* >( index.internalPointer( ) );
    ModelItem* parent = node->parent;
    ModelItem* parent2 = parent->parent;

    if ( parent2 ) // node->parent can be root node
    {
      auto it = std::find_if( parent2->childs.begin( ), parent2->childs.end( ),
                              [&]( ModelItem* child ){ return child == parent; } );

      if ( it != parent2->childs.end( ) )
      {
        int row = std::distance( parent2->childs.begin( ), it );
        to_return = createIndex( row, 0, parent );
      }
    }
  }

  return to_return;
}
```

Next method: SetGroup. With this method we can add data to the model:

```
void CustomModel::SetGroup( const QString& groupName,
                            const std::vector< std::pair< QString, QString > >& items )
{
  // Notify to view that we will insert a new group
  beginInsertRows( QModelIndex( ), rootNode.childs.size( ), rootNode.childs.size( ) );

  ModelItem* groupNode = new ModelItem( groupName );
  rootNode.AddChild( groupNode );

  for ( auto it = items.begin( ); it != items.end( ); ++it )
  {
    ModelItem* node = new ModelItem( it->first );
    node->name = it->first;
    node->IPaddr = it->second;
    groupNode->AddChild( node );
  }

  endInsertRows( );
}
```

ResetModel method simply clean the view:

```
void CustomModel::ResetModel( )
{
  beginResetModel( );
  rootNode= ModelItem( "root" );
  endResetModel( );
}
```

With model implementation completed, we only need to send data to model and link model and view:

```
QTreeView* treeView_4 = new QTreeView( tab_10 );
CustomModel* model = new CustomModel( this );

std::vector< std::pair< QString, QString > > data;
data.push_back( std::make_pair( "node1", "" ) );
data.push_back( std::make_pair( "node2", "" ) );

model->SetGroup( "Group 1", data );

data.push_back( std::make_pair( "node3", "" ) );
model->SetGroup( "Group 2", data );

treeView4->setModel( model );
```

Comment: But the OP asked about QStandardItemModel, which works with QTreeView, no?